# Enhanced dictation not found on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I cannot find the button of enhanced dictation on my Mac OS, in Keyboard->dictation of System preferences. Is it normal? I am using Mac OS 10.15.5.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that with Catalina Apple has changed naming conventions and "Enhanced Dictation" is no longer something that is turned on/off in that way.

According to this KB article https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210539

> macOS Catalina introduces Voice Control, a new way to fully control
> your Mac entirely with your voice. Voice Control uses the Siri
> speech-recognition engine to improve on the Enhanced Dictation feature
> available in earlier versions of macOS.

It seems the procedure starts in System Preferences > Accessibility > Voice Control. And is Apple's "replacement' for "Enhanced Dictation."